# reverse the arrays using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was reading STL tutorials from topcoder site. This code was given while explaining iterators. Here they are comparing addresses to reverse the array.

I didn't get this, how is it working?
Do iterators also work the same way as operations on addresses instead of elements?

```
void reverse_array(int *A, int N) {
    int *first = A, *last = A+N-1;
    while(first < last) {
        Swap(*first, *last);
        first++;
        last--;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the function did you not understand?

Comment: Assume `i` and `j` are both valid indices of `A` (i.e. both are between `0` and `N-1` inclusive)   If `first` points to `A[i]` and `last` points to `A[j]`, then `first < last` is only true if  `i < j`.

Comment: I didn't follow your question **iterators also works in the same way that is operations on addresses instead of elements?**

Comment: I recommend you get a piece of paper and a pen and make a note of each variable, what it contains or what it points to and work through the function one statement at a time updating the variables on your piece of paper as appropriate.

Comment: The address `A + i` corresponds to `&A[i]` . It may be the point that you miss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterator allow us to think of a container as a sequence of elements.

It does not matter what the container is. For example `vector`, `set`, `map` are different containers, but iterators allow us to process sequences of elements from these containers without worrying how the container is implemented behind the scenes.

**An iterator is an object that works like a pointer by design.**

> Note: `operator<<()` is not overloaded for iterators

if you want to reverse an array, try this using STL:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    array<int,10> arr{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

    reverse(arr.begin(), arr.end());

    for (const auto &elem : arr) 
        cout << elem << " ";

return 0 ; 
}
```

You can further study iterators:

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterators-c-stl/